# tikz: help with this foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, foreach

i'm getting an error in this code, can someone help me. I'm trying to create two concentric cycles, but it doesn't seems to work.

```
\def\n{10}
\defn\radio{3.00cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}
    {
    \coordinate (cn\x) at ({(1+2*\x)*180/\n-90}:\radio);
    \node (n\x) at (cn\x) {$n_\x$};
    \coordinate (cm\x) at ({(1+2*\x)*180/\n-45}:(\radio+1));
    \node (m\x) at (cm\x) {$m_\x$};
    }
\end{tickzpicture}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be careful of spelling mistakes, you wrote `\end{tickzpicture}`. Also, you can specify `\radio` as `\def\radio{3}`. A tikzpicture is by default on 1 = 1cm, so no need to specify it.

Finally, the error comes out because of this: `...:(\radio+1));` If you want to enclose a calculation, then you need to use curly brackets, because otherwise Tikz is going to confuse them with the other ones.

Also, since your `\x` reaches 10, you need also enclose it within curly brackets, like `$n_{\x}$`, otherwise, you'll get only the first number properly displayed, like in this image:

[image]

### Update

If you want to add arcs that link the nodes, there are two ways. The first one would be to add this code:

```
\foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 1)] in {1,...,\n,1}{%
    \draw (n\lastx) to [bend right=10] (n\x);
    \draw (m\lastx) to [bend right=10] (m\x);
}
```

The curves will be very similar to a circle, but not 100%. And here the second method comes in handy. Basically you draw two circles in the background and then fill the nodes with a white color. Now you have a perfectly circular link to all nodes. I would suggest this method.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\n{10}
\def\radio{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (\radio);
\draw (0,0) circle (\radio+1);
\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}{
    \coordinate (cn\x) at ({(1+2*\x)*180/\n-90}:\radio);
    \node[fill=white] (n\x) at (cn\x) {$n_{\x}$};
    \coordinate (cm\x) at ({(1+2*\x)*180/\n-45}:{\radio+1});
    \node[fill=white] (m\x) at (cm\x) {$m_{\x}$};
}

\node at (0,5) {Using circles};
\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
\node at (0,5) {Using a $\backslash$foreach statement};
\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}{
    \coordinate (cn\x) at ({(1+2*\x)*180/\n-90}:\radio);
    \node[fill=white] (n\x) at (cn\x) {$n_{\x}$};
    \coordinate (cm\x) at ({(1+2*\x)*180/\n-45}:{\radio+1});
    \node[fill=white] (m\x) at (cm\x) {$m_{\x}$};
}
\foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 1)] in {1,...,\n,1}{%
    \draw (n\lastx) to [bend right=10] (n\x);
    \draw (m\lastx) to [bend right=10] (m\x);
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Braces are needed if the calculation has parentheses in them.

Comment: @LuisGómezGuzmán See updated answer for the arcs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Is there a way to do something similar by using the \path and \edge commands, something like

    \path
    \foreach \x in {1,...,{\n-1}}
        {
        (n{\x}) edge[bend right=20] (n_{\x+1});
        }

It would be helpful not just for this cycle, but for other graphs i need to draw, and most of them have labels in the arcs

Comment: @LuisGómezGuzmán Not sure what you mean, but if those are different cases, I suggest posting another question. You can link to this one as context.