# foreach loop for adding arcs using commands path and edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, foreach, arc, edge

i want to know how to use the foreach loop for adding arcs using commands \path and edge. For instance, the following code generates a cycle and the task is to add the arcs not manually:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,automata,arrows,shadows,patterns,shapes}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\rnodo}
\newlength{\radio}
\setlength{\rnodo}{10pt}
\setlength{\radio}{3.00cm}
\tikzstyle{nondirected}=[thick]
\tikzstyle{labels}=[inner sep=0pt,font=\scriptsize,auto,circle]
\tikzstyle{main node}=[outer sep=1,inner sep=0,ellipse,thick,draw,minimum size=2\rnodo,fill=black!10]

\newcommand\n{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}{
    \coordinate (cn\x) at ({(1+2*\x)*180/\n-90}:\radio);
    \node (n\x) at (cn\x) {$n_{\x}$};
}

\path[nondirected]
(n1) edge node[labels] {$\oplus$}  (n2)
(n2) edge node[labels] {$\oplus$}  (n3)
(n3) edge node[labels] {$\ominus$}  (n4)
(n4) edge node[labels] {$\ocircle$}  (n5)
(n5) edge node[labels] {$\ocircle$}  (n6)
(n6) edge node[labels] {$\oplus$}  (n7)
(n7) edge node[labels] {$\oplus$}  (n8)
(n8) edge node[labels] {$\ominus$}  (n9)
(n9) edge node[labels] {$\ominus$}  (n10)
(n10) edge node[labels] {$\ocircle$}  (n1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this [LINK](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255180/tikz-help-with-this-foreach-loop/255184?noredirect=1#comment611358_255184/), I've been given some alternatives using command \draw. I've tried to adapt it, but with no luck so far.

Comment: Copy-paste lines of code is easier in this case, no much gain out of a loop here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All can be done with two simple loops: one to place the nodes and the other one to place the links and labels:

```
\def\n{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,\the\numexpr\n-1\relax}
    \node (n\x) at ({(1+2*(\x+1))*180/\n-90}:\radio) {$n_{\the\numexpr\x+1\relax}$};
\foreach \Texto [count=\x]  in {\oplus,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ocircle,\ocircle,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ominus}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ttt}{int(mod(\numexpr\x+\n-1\relax,\n))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mmm}{int(mod(\numexpr\x+\n-2\relax,\n))}
  \draw[nondirected] (n\mmm) -- node[labels] {$\Texto$} (n\ttt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,automata,arrows,shadows,patterns,shapes}

\newlength\rnodo
\newlength\radio
\setlength{\rnodo}{10pt}
\setlength{\radio}{3.00cm}

\tikzset{
  nondirected/.style={thick},
  labels/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    font=\scriptsize,
    auto,
    circle},
  main node/.style={
    outer sep=1,
    inner sep=0,
    ellipse,
    thick,
    draw,
    minimum size=2\rnodo,
    fill=black!10}
}

\begin{document}

\def\n{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,\the\numexpr\n-1\relax}
    \node (n\x) at ({(1+2*(\x+1))*180/\n-90}:\radio) {$n_{\the\numexpr\x+1\relax}$};
\foreach \Texto [count=\x]  in {\oplus,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ocircle,\ocircle,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ominus}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ttt}{int(mod(\numexpr\x+\n-1\relax,\n))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mmm}{int(mod(\numexpr\x+\n-2\relax,\n))}
  \draw[nondirected] (n\mmm) -- node[labels] {$\Texto$} (n\ttt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Explanation

The first loop

```
\foreach \x in {0,...,\the\numexpr\n-1\relax}
    \node (n\x) at ({(1+2*(\x+1))*180/\n-90}:\radio) {$n_{\the\numexpr\x+1\relax}$};
```

is clear; it's almost the original, but I looped from `0` to `n-1` instead of from `1` to `n` because in the second loop some modular arithmetic will be used.

The second loop (forgetting the labels in this explanation, which are not important here) could be simplified to

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}
{
  \draw[nondirected] (n int(mod(\x+\n-2,\n))) -- (n int(mod(\x+\n-1,\n)));
}
```

so it joins `n(n-1)` to `n0`, `n0` to `n1`,...,`n(n-2)` to `n(n-1)`. So, simply changing \n to 20 and providing the labels for the additional elements, as in

```
\def\n{20}
...
\foreach \Texto [count=\x]  in {\oplus,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ocircle,\ocircle,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ominus,\oplus,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ocircle,\ocircle,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ominus}
{...}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, but the math labels weren't working in a foreach for me.

Comment: Thanks!!! Just one question: how to make the "9" in the foreach loop depend on \n? Like \foreach \x in {0,...,\n-1}, but it didn't work

Comment: @LuisGómezGuzmán You're welcome! Please see my updated answer. Now, everything is dependant on `\n` so you just have to change `\n` and provide enough labels in the second loop to easily get the shape with a variable number of vertices. See the example at the bottom.

Comment: thankz!!, i also solved it replacing \pgfmathsetmacro{\ed}{int(mod(\x+9,10))} by \pgfmathsetmacro{\ed}{int(mod(\x+9,10)+1)}.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat crude, but serviceable...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node [regular polygon, regular polygon sides=10, 
  draw, minimum size=5cm, rotate=-108] (p) {} 
  \foreach \l [count=\i] in {\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ocircle,\ocircle,
      \oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ominus,\oplus}{ 
    node [circle, inner sep=0, fill=white] at (p.corner \i) {\strut$n_{\i}$}
    node [circle, font=\scriptsize, anchor=\i*36+54-108, inner sep=0] 
      at (p.side \i) {$\l$} };
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of trouble with the labels because I wanted to use an array list, but it refuses to work although the code is fine. However it's getting late here, so I'll take a look at it tomorrow. For now, here's the foreach for the lines.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,automata,arrows,shadows,patterns,shapes}

\newcommand{\rnodo}{10}
\newcommand{\radio}{3.00cm}
\tikzstyle{nondirected}=[thick]
\tikzstyle{labels}=[inner sep=0pt,font=\scriptsize,auto,circle]
\tikzstyle{main node}=[outer sep=1,inner sep=0,ellipse,thick,draw,minimum size=2pt*\rnodo,fill=black!10]



\begin{document}
\def\n{10}
%\newcommand\mylist{{"$\oplus$","$\oplus$","$\ominus$","$\ocircles$","$\ocircles$","$\oplus$","$\oplus$","$\ominus$","$\ominus$"}}

\begin{tikzpicture}   
\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}{
    \coordinate (cn\x) at ({(1+2*\x)*180/\n-90}:\radio);
    \node (n\x) at (cn\x) {$n_{\x}$};
}

\foreach \lab [count=\xi, remember=\xi as \lastx (initially 1)] in {1,...,11}{
\ifnum\xi<11
\path[nondirected] (n\lastx) edge node[labels] {} (n\xi);
\else
\path[nondirected] (n10) edge node[labels] {$\ocircle$} (n1);
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```