# adding labels after the arcs with a foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, arc

I have this code that generates a cycle graph with labels in the arcs (reference [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255845/foreach-loop-for-adding-arcs-using-commands-path-and-edge/255857?noredirect=1#comment612914_255857)):

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,automata,arrows,shadows,patterns,shapes}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\rnodo}
\newlength{\radio}
\setlength{\rnodo}{10pt}
\setlength{\radio}{3.00cm}
\tikzstyle{nondirected}=[thick]
\tikzstyle{labels}=[inner sep=0pt,font=\scriptsize,auto,circle]
\tikzstyle{main node}=[outer sep=1,inner sep=0,ellipse,thick,draw,minimum  size=2\rnodo,fill=black!10]

\def\n{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}
    {
    \coordinate (cn\x) at ({(1+2*\x)*180/\n}:\radio);
    \node[main node] (n\x) at (cn\x) {$n_{\x}$};        
    }

\foreach \lab [count=\x]  in     {\oplus,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ocircle,\ocircle,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ominus}
    {
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\ed}{int(mod(\x+9,10)+1)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{int(mod(\x+8,10)+1)}
   \path[nondirected] (n\st) edge[bend right=10] node[labels] {$\lab$} (n\ed);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My question is, if it is possible to add the labels of the arcs with a separate `\foreach` loop after drawing the arcs with the following `\foreach` loop:

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}
    {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ed}{int(mod(\x+9,10)+1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{int(mod(\x+8,10)+1)}
    \path[nondirected] (n\st) edge[bend right=10] (n\ed);
    }
```

And then add the labels with another loop...?_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a separate loop for the labels as this:

```
\foreach \lab [count=\x, evaluate=\x as \ang using {360/\n*(\x-1)}] in 
   {\ominus,\oplus,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ocircle,\ocircle,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus}
   {
   \node[labels] at (\ang:\radio-2ex) {$\lab$} ;
   }
```

Here, we calculated the position of the label by `{360/\n*(\x-1)}` and drew the label by the usual `\node[labels] at (\ang:\radius) {$\lab$};`. We subtract from the radius `\radio` a small length `2ex` for the labels not to override the edges.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,automata,arrows,shadows,patterns,shapes}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\rnodo}
\newlength{\radio}
\setlength{\rnodo}{10pt}
\setlength{\radio}{3.00cm}
\tikzstyle{nondirected}=[thick]
\tikzstyle{labels}=[inner sep=0pt,font=\scriptsize,auto,circle]
\tikzstyle{main node}=[outer sep=1,inner sep=0,ellipse,thick,draw,minimum  size=2\rnodo,fill=black!10]

\def\n{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}
    {
    \coordinate (cn\x) at ({(1+2*\x)*180/\n}:\radio);
    \node[main node] (n\x) at (cn\x) {$n_{\x}$};        
    }

\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}
    {
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\ed}{int(mod(\x+9,10)+1)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{int(mod(\x+8,10)+1)}
   \path[nondirected] (n\st) edge[bend right=10] (n\ed);
   }
\foreach \lab [count=\x, evaluate=\x as \ang using {360/\n*(\x-1)}] in 
   {\ominus,\oplus,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus,\ocircle,\ocircle,\oplus,\oplus,\ominus}
   {
   \node[labels] at (\ang:\radio-2ex) {$\lab$} ;
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to define a list (?) of the labels and then call that list inside the loop?